# how to input total number of test case in hackerrank in python language

Tags: python, testcase, cp

I want to run my program for total number of testcases from user input in hackerrank

Here in my code :

```py
def sub_lists (l):
    lists = [[]]
    for i in range(len(l) + 1):
        for j in range(i):
            lists.append(l[j: i])
    return lists
 
# driver code
T=int(input())
while (T-- is not 0):

    n,k=map(int,input().split())
    l1 = list(int(num) for num in input().strip().split())[:n]
    list_of_list=sub_lists(l1)
    list_of_list=[sum(x)  for x in list_of_list if sum(x)%k==0 and sum(x)>0 ]   
print(len(list_of_list))
```

here `T` is the user input;

Answer (score 0):

```
TestCasse=int(input())
while TestCase>0:
     #your code
     TestCode-=1
#or
for i in range(TestCase):
    your code
```

Answer (score 0):

`T` isn't used anywhere inside the loop, so there's no need to start counting at `T` and decrement towards `0`.

All you need to do is to repeat the loop body `T` times, so just use a `for` loop:

```py
for _ in range(T):
    n,k=map(int,input().split())
    ... [rest of loop body]
```